# Como subtrair uma data com relação a data atual do sistema

Tags: php, mysql, data

Quero subtrair a data atual do sistema com a data que está gravada no mysql.
Eu insiro a data no mysql atraves do INSERT, de forma manual, pois nem sempre irei usar a data atual para inserir no sistema.

Preciso saber quantos dias tem de diferença entre a data atual e a data cadastrada.

É para um sistema de biblioteca, onde insiro a data que o livro foi emprestada.
no relatorio de livros, se a data atual - a data do cadastro for maior ou igual a 8 ( >= '8' ) deverá mostrar que está em atraso em tantos dias. mas não estou conseguindo. me perdi no meio do codigo por causa das datas.

```
fico grato se alguem puder me ajudar



    $sql_visualizar = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cadastro_alunos ORDER BY serie, numero, data");
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array ($sql_visualizar)){
        $pega_numero = $linha ['numero'];
        $pega_aluno = $linha ['nome'];
        $pega_serie = $linha ['serie'];
        $pega_n_livro = $linha ['n_livro'];
        $pega_livro = $linha ['livro'];
        $pega_emprestado = $linha ['emprestado'];
        $pega_data = $linha ['data'];
        $data_sistema = $linha [date("d-m-Y")];

        //aqui é para comparar as datas, se a data do emprestimo for maior que 8 dias (o sistema conta um dia a mais) realizar a função $pega_atraso
        $pega_atraso = $data_sistema - $pega_data;

    ?>
<?
if ($pega_emprestado == 'sim'){
?>
    //aqui fica os campos da tabela que uso, por isso estes não precisam aparecer aqui.
        <?

      //aqui é onde se encontra a função do atraso

if  ($pega_atraso >= '8'){

    echo "ENTREGA ATRASADA EM $pega_atraso dias";
    else 
        echo "No prazo de Leitura";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Qual o formato que vc recebe do banco em `$pega_data = $linha ['data'];`? Em tempo: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: recebo no formato padrão ('Y/m/d')

Comment: Então tente usar `$data_sistema = $linha [date("Y-m-d")];`...

Comment: E vc também precisa conveter em objeto Datetime (ou usar `ceil` como na resposta do Alan) antes de comparar as datas, vou postar uma resposta mais detalhada, mas o acho que o ideal é fazer direto no SQL mesmo, na linha da resposta do Willian...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o esclarecimento nos comentários da pergunta, vejo dois problemas no seu código:

1 - Você está pegando a data do banco em formato `('Y/m/d')`, e comparando com uma data em formato `('d/m/Y')`;

2 - Ao invés de calcular a diferença de tempo entre objetos de tempo (`Datetime` por exemplo) você está fazendo uma **operação matemática entre strings**. Quando você faz:

```
$pega_data = $linha ['data'];
```

Recebe do banco uma string, por exemplo:

> 2010-11-19

E quando cria a data atual em:

```
$data_sistema = $linha [date("d-m-Y")];
```

Tem também uma string:

> 19-11-2015

Então quando você faz:

```
$pega_atraso = $data_sistema - $pega_data;
```

o PHP vai pegar os dois primeiros números antes do sinal `-`, e fazer a operação.

```
$pega_data = "19-11-2010";
$data_sistema = date("Y-m-d");

$pega_atraso = $data_sistema - $pega_data;

var_dump($pega_data);
var_dump($data_sistema);
var_dump($pega_atraso);
```

E a saída será:

```
string '19-11-2010' (length=10)
string '2015-11-19' (length=10)
int 1996 // 2015 - 19
```

Veja no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/RVWfZZ).

Então o que você precisa, além de deixar os formatos iguais, é transformar num objeto `Datetime` antes de subtrair:

```
$pega_data = "2010-11-19";
$data_sistema = date("Y-m-d");

$pega_data_Time = new DateTime($pega_data);
$data_sistema_Time = new DateTime($data_sistema);

$pega_diferenca = $data_sistema_Time->diff($pega_data_Time);

var_dump($pega_data);
var_dump($data_sistema);
var_dump($pega_diferenca);
```

A saída conterá o seguinte objeto `DateInterval`:

```
string '2010-11-19' (length=10)
string '2015-11-19' (length=10)
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 5
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 14
  public 'i' => int 51
  public 's' => int 35
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 1826
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

Onde este trecho aponta o resultado que você procura:

```
  public 'y' => int 5
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 0
```

No caso, 5 anos, 0 meses e 0 dias, que pode ser obtido através do operador `->`, assim:

```
echo "A diferença de tempo é de " . $pega_diferenca->y . " anos , " .  $pega_diferenca->m . " meses, e " . $pega_diferenca->d . " dias.";
```

Veja no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/xDG3XC).

Comment: o formato de data errado eu reparei depois e corrigi.
vou agora  transformar num objeto Datetime como vc disse e as devidas alterações e posto depois se consegui, vlw.

Comment: consegui fazer assim como vc me explicou @gustavox porem deu um erro, não sei bem se é erro ou se tem como ocultar.

aparece toda a codificação antes da minha tabela.
como ocultar esta codificação ?????

salvei como pdf a pagina de como ficou, da uma olhada ai se puder, esta salvo no google drive, está ok arquivo.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7MAXH1JQy95RUlxd21JUVN3R2s

Comment: Tire os `var_dump`, eles servem apenas pra vc visualizar a saída do código. @GuilhermeHenrique

Comment: perfeito. deu certinho aqui.
tu  salvou meu dia.
comecei com codificação php faz 2 semanas, e criei uma pagina desde o 0, com cadastros, relatorios, edição e exclusão. esta era a unica parte q não conseguia de modo algum. 

vlw mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Faça direto no MySQL

Leia sobre a função [datediff](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/196414)

Veja este fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b7184/1 que eu mostro como utilizar e um exemplo funcional quase semelhante a sua tabela.

Apenas por questão de agilidade, segue snippet que pega a quantidade de dias em atraso:

[SQL Fiddle][1]

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table cadastro_alunos (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  numero int not null,
  data datetime not null default current_timestamp
);

insert into cadastro_alunos (numero, data) values
(1, '2015-11-19 00:00:00'),
(2, '2015-11-18 00:00:00'),
(3, '2015-11-17 00:00:00'),
(4, '2015-11-10 00:00:00'),
(5, '2015-11-9 00:00:00'),
(6, '2015-11-1 00:00:00'),
(7, '2015-08-21 00:00:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  id,
  numero,
  data,
  datediff(now(), data) as dias_em_atraso
from cadastro_alunos
```

Comment: +1 O fiddle neste caso ajuda muito mesmo, porque o snippet daqui não suporta sql,  mas não deixe de colocar o código completo aqui, porque o link do fiddle pode quebrar e a resposta não vai ficar completa.

Comment: De fato, irei fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

Em PHP as funções `mktime()` e `time()`  podem te ajudar:

Considerando que se tenha a data do emprestimo como `2015-29-10` de uma maneira bem didática teríamos:

```
<?php 
    $data1 = "2015-10-29"; 
    $data1 = explode("-", $data1); //Transforma em array
    $data1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, $data1[1], $data1[2], $data1[0]); // Utiliza o array para pegar o unix timestamp da data em questão

    $data2 = time(); //Pega o unix timestamp da momento atual

    $diferenca = ceil(($data2-$data1)/86400); // faz a diferença dividida por 86400 para termos o resultado em dias e arredondamos para cima com ceil
    echo $diferenca; 
?>
```